# A button that is rendered with the value of an attribut of a selected row in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, selection

I am working on jsf project and i have a p:dataTable and the delete button that is outside must be rendered with the value of a selected row in the dataTable. I tried the `idDataTable.#{item.attribut}` but didn't work.

PS: when the button was inside the row it worked with `#{item.attribut}`

Here's the code below. I hope I can find response and thank you a lot.

```
<h:form styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
    <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
   <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{factureController.items.size()>0}">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-9">
   </div>   
   <div class="col-lg-3">
   <p:commandButton action="#{factureController.prepareCreate}" ajax ="false" icon ="fa fa-plus"/>                           
                <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />
                            <h:outputText value=" "/>
                            <p:commandButton rendered ="singleDT#{item.suppression}" action="#{factureController.destroy}"
                                          process="singleDT" 
                                             update="message"   icon ="fa fa-times" ajax ="false">
                                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="êtes vous sûre de vouloire supprimer?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        
                            <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                                <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                            </p:confirmDialog> 
                    <p:commandButton action="#{factureController.prepareEdit}"  icon="fa fa-edit" ajax ="false"/>
                    </div>
                    
 
                              </div>   
                    
                    <p:dataTable value="#{factureController.items}" rows="10"
                        id="singleDT"   selectionMode="single" selection="#{factureController.selected}" rowKey="#{item.id}"                                 
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"  var="item" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" rowStyleClass="odd gradeA,even gradeA" >
                       
                        
                        
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                           </f:facet>
                        
                        
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_id}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_dateCreation}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.dateCreation}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_totaltva}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.totaltva}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_totalHT}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.totalHT}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_totalTTC}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.totalTTC}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_user}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.user}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Title_client}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.client}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                            </f:facet>
                           
                           

                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </h:form>
```

Comment: the delete button is in the top after the growl tag

Comment: Break down your problem... first try to get the selected row in a field/property in your bean.Try to have the value of the commandButton point to that field (and the attribute of it) and make sure on selection you update the button. All a sort of basic ajax 'problem'

Comment: thank you i will try that solution   please if you give me a favour advice me how to proceed to read these languages (jsf, ajax...) i know how to work with them but i don't have a solid knowledge i always look by here and there for information

Comment: i tryed  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{factureController.onRowSelect}" update=":form"  />
 <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{factureController.onRowUnselect}" update=":form"  />

Comment: Your form does not have an id "form", so either add it or update @form

Comment: i added an id to my form but same result